# How would i get specific data value from a csv file without using modules?

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a project in which I'm not allowed to import any modules.
I need to do some calculations with specific data values from a CSV file, but in order to do that i would need to find them first. I don't know how to get my program to find the values of the 3rd,4th and 5th column in a specific row where column[1] is a specific number. Since the numbers in a given CSV file for column[1] would not necessarily be in numerical order, i need to arrange the 3rd,4th and 5th column in numerical order of the column[1] ascending from 1. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
J1283,1,-0.837028634,0.724271463,0.718634041
J1283,2,-0.836510147,-0.722637551,0.718199937
J1283,6,-0.833234927,-0.722650022,0.71765857
J1283,4,-0.829230547,-0.723707934,-0.717132914
J1283,3,-0.81601564,-0.722668297,0.717088805
J1283,5,-0.808930225,-0.722808277,0.718237702
```

Answer (score 1):

CSV is nothing but a file where values are separated by commas (Comma-Separated Values, that's the name).

You just need to read the file and parse it line by line :

```
def read_csv(filename: str) -> list[list[str]]:
    values = []
    with open(p, 'r') as f:
        for l in f.readlines():
            values.append(l.split(','))
    return values
```

This needs absolutely no `import` statement.
You can modulate this to go in accordance to what you want to do, like converting the 2nd column to int and the 3rd to last column to float :

```
def read_csv(filename: str) -> list[list[str]]:
    values = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for l in f.readlines():
            values.append(l.strip('\n').split(','))
    for row in values:
        row[1] = int(row[1])
        row[2:5] = [float(i) for i in row[2:5]]
    return values
```

The, you can use this result to sort your rows with the `sort` method :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    values = read_csv('my_file.csv')
    values.sort(key=lambda row: row[1])
```

Result is the following :

```
['J1283', 1, -0.837028634, 0.724271463, 0.718634041]
['J1283', 2, -0.836510147, -0.722637551, 0.718199937]
['J1283', 3, -0.81601564, -0.722668297, 0.717088805]
['J1283', 4, -0.829230547, -0.723707934, -0.717132914]
['J1283', 5, -0.808930225, -0.722808277, 0.718237702]
['J1283', 6, -0.833234927, -0.722650022, 0.71765857]
```

Comment: Thanks, @imperosol. I sort of understand it now. Also, in the csv file I was given, column[0] isn't always the same. For example, a chunk of the file is as follows:

J7033,7,0.878833765,0.72272582,0.725302538
J7033,8,-0.867293118,-0.723656965,-0.724962529

J1283,1,-0.837028634,0.724271463,0.718634041
J1283,2,-0.836510147,-0.722637551,0.718199937

How would i sort column[1] only in which column[0] is the same. For example, if column[0] is x in 5 rows and column[0] is y in another 5 rows, how would I sort the 5 column[1] values for x separately from the 5 column[1] values for y?

Comment: you can extract the values you want to sort with their indexes. You can then sort the resulting list and finally replace it with the indexes you kept.